# How to set text for multiple EditTexts in Android

Tags: java, android

First of all i would like to introduce you with my application, so you have a better point of view what i need. I have database with three tables `days`, `weeks`, `weekdays` and in one Activity i'm fetching all items from days table by selected week, but i don't know how to set text to all members of that class Day. I will show you in following example what i want.

I have achieved setting text to multiple EditTexts, but with many repetition. I want to do this with arrays and loop. I have succeed initializing all EditTexts using array and loop, but i don't know how to implement setting text for all EditTexts.

This is repetition part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
        // Monday
        Day day1 = days.get(0);
        etNasteMonday.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getNaste()));
        etInsulinMondayBeforeBreak.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getInsulinBeforeBreak()));
        etDiabetesMondayAfterBreak.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getDiabetesAfterBreak()));
        etDiabetesMondayBeforeLaunch.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getDiabetesBeforeLaunch()));
        etInsulinMondayBeforeLaunch.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getInsulinBeforeLaunch()));
        etDiabetesMondayAfterLaunch.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getDiabetesAfterLaunch()));
        etDiabetesMondayBeforeDinner.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getDiabetesBeforeDinner()));
        etInsulinMondayBeforeDinner.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getInsulinBeforeDinner()));
        etDiabetesMondayAfterDinner.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getDiabetesAfterDinner()));
        etDiabetesMondayBeforeSleep.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getDiabetesBeforeSleep()));
        etInsulinMondayAfterSleep.setText(String.valueOf(day1.getInsulinBeforeSleep()));
        // Tuesday
        Day day2 = days.get(1);
        etNasteUtorak.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getNaste()));
        etInsulinUtorakPreDorucka.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getInsulinBeforeBreak()));
        etDiabetesUtorakPosleDorucka.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getDiabetesAfterBreak()));
        etDiabetesUtorakPreRucka.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getDiabetesBeforeLaunch()));
        etInsulinUtorakPreRucka.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getInsulinBeforeLaunch()));
        etDiabetesUtorakPosleRucka.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getDiabetesAfterLaunch()));
        etDiabetesUtorakPreVecere.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getDiabetesBeforeDinner()));
        etInsulinUtorakPreVecere.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getInsulinBeforeDinner()));
        etDiabetesUtorakPosleVecere.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getDiabetesAfterDinner()));
        etDiabetesUtorakPredSpavanje.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getDiabetesBeforeSleep()));
        etInsulinUtorakPredSpavanje.setText(String.valueOf(day2.getInsulinBeforeSleep()));
    }
```

What should i do to make this more efficient and easier for program to read and how to implement within this code:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.et_naste_monday, R.id.et_insulin_monday_before_breakf, R.id.et_posle_dorucka_monday, R.id.et_pre_rucka_moday,
    R.id.et_insulin_monday_pre_rucka, R.id.et_posle_rucka_monday, R.id.et_pre_vecere_moday, R.id.et_insulin_monday_pre_vecere, R.id.et_posle_vecere_monday,
    R.id.et_pred_spavanje_moday, R.id.et_insulin_monday_pred_spavanje};
List<Day> days = mDatabase.getAllDaysByWeek(week.getTitle());

for (int id : ids) {
        EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(id);
        values.add(t.getText().toString());
        t.addTextChangedListener(this);
        applyChangedEditTextColor(false, values, t);
        for (Day day : days) {
            // Here i should do the same part as i done it in above example
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view with all these edittexts, and set a method populate(Day day) in which you will fill all those setTexts. Then you can do

```
mondayView.populate(day.get(0));
tuesdayView.populate(day.get(1));
```

More info about custom views:
https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html
https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Comment: Should i write in that method everything i have written above where i'm setting text to every individual edittext?

Comment: yes, you will have to write all the settexts for a day, but only for one day

Comment: But you see that i'm initializing all EditTexts using for loop and in that for loop i only have one view of edittext.

Comment: I didn't develop in Android in a while but what you a telling is to create a view (DayFields) with all the textfields. Include it a number of time (one per day). Then creating a method with as input the view (or view id) and the day instance ? This is what I understand but this is a bit vague for newbies ;-)

Comment: @AxelH yes, that's it. A view with all the edittext required for a day, then an input method with his Day class as argument. I think a custom view is a basic thing, that's why I left two links to him to investigate

Comment: It's the next level for GUI in Android. This is simple if you understand what is a View. You should explain just a bit, create a dummy view with two fields to show how to include it, and how to get it from is id. The method is basic when you have the view so this is not necessary a guess.